# NextJS Microfrontend (MFE) - resolving expose incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, micro-frontend

I have been following blog on NextJS MFE. However I have hit a dead end and would like some help.

https://thekevinwang.com/2021/03/26/micro-frontends-nextjs/

I have 2 apps - one `shell` and other `ranked-app`

The shell app's `next.config.js` is

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = options.webpack.container;

    config.plugins.push(
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'webapp',
        remotes: {
          'rankedApp': 'rankedApp@http://localhost:3502/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js'
        }
      })
    );

    config.cache = false;

    return config;
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and the `ranked-app` next config is

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = options.webpack.container;

    config.plugins.push(
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'rankedApp',
        library: {
          type: 'var',
          name: 'rankedApp'
        },
        filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
          './Example': './src/components/Example'
        },
        remotes: {},
        shared: []
      })
    );

    config.cache = false;

    config.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:3502/_next/';

    return config;
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

However, when I attempt to import the `Example` component from `ranked-app`, the `remoteEntry` gets loaded from `http://localhost:3502`, but the request for chunk `src_component_Example_tsx.js` is relative to `http://localhost:3501` interesting it ignores `publicPath` in `ranked-app`. Any pointers where I am going wrong could be nice to see.

[image]

[image]

```
import React, { FC, Fragment } from "react";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const RankedAppExample = dynamic(
  async () => {
    return await import("rankedApp/Example");
  },
  {
    ssr: false,
    loading: ({ error }) => {
      if (error) {
        return <Fragment>Error</Fragment>;
      }
      return <Fragment>Loading</Fragment>;
    }
  }
);

interface HomeProps {}

const Home: FC<HomeProps> = (props: HomeProps) => {
  return <Fragment>Home <RankedAppExample /></Fragment>;
};

export default Home;
```